# Using "check" package causes another package to error

Tags: validation, meteor, package

I'm using the [Check package](http://docs.meteor.com/#check_package) to validate parameters passed to Meteor methods. And I'm using [Audit argument checks](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/audit-argument-checks) to enforce this.

However, I've added another package, [Meteor Tags](https://atmospherejs.com/patrickleet/tags) and when I try to use methods from the Tags package, I get a server error "Exception while invoking method '/patterns/addTag' Error: Did not check() all arguments during call to '/patterns/addTag'".

I think I understand why this error happens - the method in the Tags package doesn't check its inputs, so Audit Argument Checks generates an error. But I can't find any way around this, apart from 1) don't enforce checking, or 2) hack the Tags package methods so they use check. Neither of these seems like a great option - checking server parameters is a good idea, and hacking a package is not very maintainable.

Does anybody know if there is any smart way to use 'Audit argument checks' with packages that provide new server methods? I have looked at the Check documents, and searched online, but I haven't found an answer.

I hope this question makes sense.

Comment: Your assessment is correct - you have to drop the audit package, fork the tags package, or open an issue and hope the package author fixes.

Comment: Thanks. I guess this would explain why more people don't use "Audit argument checks", if you have to drop it in order to use carelessly-written packages. It would be really useful if "Audit argument checks" allowed you to specify exception methods for this kind of situation.

Comment: I added a more complete answer below, which addresses this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `audit-argument-checks` is like saying: *"I want to be serious about the security of the methods in my app."* It's global to all methods in your app's codebase, including the methods from your installed packages.

There is no way to specify which parts of the app get checked, as that would be the equivalent of saying: *"I want to be serious about the security of the methods I've written, but I don't care about the security holes created by some pacakges"* (which doesn't make a lot of sense).

**Note to package authors**

Check your method arguments. It's not hard, and it prevents this situation from happening. Frankly, a package without this basic security really shouldn't be installed in the first place.

**What you should do**

Unless you have a throwaway app, I wouldn't recommend removing `audit-argument-checks`. Instead I'd do the following (assuming the package really has something of value):

1. Open an issue on github and let the maintainer know what's up.
2. Fork the code, and add the required checks. Keep this version as a [local package](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/local-packages).
3. Submit a pull request for the changes.

If all goes well, your PR will be accepted and everyone can benefit from the change. In the worst case, you'll still have a local copy that you can use in your app.